# Using Pollards rho algorithm for logarithms

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, congruences, euclidean-algorithm

I have been reading about the  [Pollard's rho algorithm for logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) on Wikipedia.

I wanted to work out an example. 
I use $n = 16$ and $p=16$ in my working. (Not sure if this is correct)
Further I use the primes  $3$ and $13$.

I think I want to solve the congruence:

$$3^{\gamma}\equiv 13 \pmod{16}$$

I let ;

$$S_0={3^2,3^5,3^8,3^{11},3^{14}}$$
$$S_1={3^0,3^3,3^6,3^9,3^{12},3^{15}}$$
$$S_2={3^1,3^4,3^7,3^{10},3^{13}}$$

Then I get $a_1=0 \mod 16$, $b_1=0 \mod 16$, $x_1=1$, $x_{21}=1$, $a_{21}=0 \mod 16$, $b_{21}=0 \mod 16$

The value I get for $r$ is then;

$$r = 0 \mod 16$$ However this is = 0, so a failure result is obtained.

1) Is there a mistake in my working, or an incorrect interpretation of the algorithm?

Then presuming a non-zero $r$, I have to work out the multiplicative inverse of $r$

2) I know one can use Euclid's Algorithm for finding multiplicative inverses. How can use this to work out this multiplicative inverse?

Comment: There is not multiplicative inverse to $0$.

Comment: In general, there is no multiplicative inverse for a [zero divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor) as well.  For $r$ to have a multiplicative inverse modulo $n$ you must have $\gcd(r,n)=1$.

Comment: If $x$ were the inverse of $-32$ mod $16$, then this absurd equivalence would hold: $1\equiv-32x\equiv0x\equiv0$. So no such $x$ exists.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compute? A discrete log, but in which group? Where does the $16$ come from? Include the full computation you did.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Alright that clears things up a bit. Your group is the multiplicative group mod $17$, it has $16$ elements. Thus the congruence $3^{\gamma} = 13$  is modulo $17$. Yet the comuputions of the functions $g,h$ is modulo $16$. But $f$ is modulo $17$. (The exponents are mod $16$, but the 'elements' are mod $17$.)

Comment: Ok, following that I still get the same answers. - what happens in the functions g, and h when combinations of mod 16 and mod 17 are used?

Comment: Why is $b_1= 0$? You use $g$ for $a_1$ but you need to use $h$ for $b_1$.  To fully follow your computations one would need $S_0,S_1,S_2$.

Comment: The $g$ and $h$ are modulo $16$.

Comment: Question updated. Ok, since $x_0=1$, and $1$ is in $S_1$, I have $b_1=h(1,0)=0 \mod 16$. If this is wrong I don't understand why.

Comment: It's true then.  This is a bit of a peculiar choice for the $S$-sets. As said the algorithm is such that it can fail. Note the "if r = 0 return failure" You hit that "failure" branch. You need to restart with a different starting value or different $S$-set until it works. Maybe just switch $S_0$ and $S_1$. If you put $3^0$ into $S_1$ you always get a failure with that initialization for $a_0,b_0,x_0$. See http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap3.pdf linked on the wikipedia page, sec 3.6.3 where it says $1 \notin S_2$ (the $S_2$ there is your $S_1$ as you index $0,1,2$ and there it's $1,2,3$)

Comment: Generally I recommend you read 3.6.3 in the linked pdf. I feel it explains things better than the Wiki page. For example it mentions the restriction that caused you problems, which is not mentioned on the Wikipedia page.  // Tangenially please use `@quid` if you want to make me notice an update, or comment on my answer.

Comment: @quid 3.6.3 in the linked PDF is very helpful thank you.

Comment: @quid I'm wondering why some people have downvoted the question. Anything I should do differently going forward?

Comment: The original form of the question was a rather basic question and then it changed a lot and was frequently edited. This is not optimal and can lead to annoyance. I do not think the current version would be poorly received. What is useful is giving the context where the problem arises. In fact you did this by mentioning Pollard; though some more details right away could have helped. Also the current formulation is still a tad unclear, I'll do a couple of small changes.

Comment: @quid Ok I'll try and put in as much relevant info as possible in the future. Sometimes in past questions including this I have just put the problem I have, then found it was just a result of something else. Would separate questions be better?

Comment: Yes, usually it is better to ask a separate question if the problem changes. For this one I would leave it as is now. I'll also  update my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second question, one can use the Euclidean algorithm to find the multiplicative inverse **if** there exists one.

Recall that some $a$ is invertible modulo $n$ if and only if $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

If this the case, then there exists $x,y$  such that $ax + ny  = 1$. This $x$ is the inverse of $a$ modulo $n$. You find these $x,y$ by the extended Euclidean algorithm (keyword Bézout coefficients).

In general you can find $x,y$  such that $ax + ny  = \gcd(a,n)$. Yet if the right hand side is not $1$ this gives no inverse. (And $\gcd(a,n)$ is the smallest positive integer such that $aX + nY  = c$ has a solution; so if it's not $1$, then you cannot find an inverse for it does not exist.)

Thus in your case you cannot find an inverse.

---

For your first question, indeed the algorithm is such that it does not guarantee a solution for every starting value. Note that it contains the possibility of outputting "failure."

In this case you need to run the algorithm anew, with different starting values for $a_0,b_0,x_0$ (but be careful to compute the $x_0$ that matches the starting value $a_0,b_0$). Or, you change the sets $S_i$.

For computing by hand this is also an option but in general one will change the starting values not the $S_i$.

**Some further remarks:**

When you compute the discrete logarithm of $13$ to base $3$ in a cyclic group of order $16$ (the $p$), then you do  this in the group  "the multiplicative group of integers modulo $17$."

Thus you are looking for a solution to 
$$3^{\gamma} \equiv 13 \pmod{17}$$
so this congruence is modulo $17$ not $16$. Thus, the sets $S_0,S_1, S_2$ are also modulo $17$.

However the definition of the functions $g$ and $h$ in the proof you mention are modulo the order of the group, so indeed $16$.

Thus you need to do some calculations modulo $17$ and some others modulo $16$.

*On the "failure."* Your choice of sets and initial values is such that you will always get a failure. The problem is that your starting values $a_0,b_0$ are $0$ and your $x_0=1$ is in $S_1$ where the $a_i,b_i$ are not changed. Thus the stay the same, which is not desirable. 
The starting values $a_0,b_0$ are $0$ are common, what is not common is to have $1$ in $S_1$. You can read this in more detail in Section 3.6.3 of Menezes, Alfred J.; van Oorschot, Paul C.; Vanstone, Scott A. (2001). "Chapter 3" Handbook of Applied Cryptography, which is linked on the Wikipedia page you mentioned.

Comment: Does this mean I need to use another congruence for my question - eg one that is $\mod 17$?

Comment: It is not clear what it means. You might want to include your computations. But, yes, on second thought you likely want  a discrete log of $13$ to base $3$ in the multiplicative group of $Z/17Z$, which is a group of order $16$, so that some of your congruences are mod $17$, yet others are mod $16$. That's however  not what you wrote.

Comment: I have just tried using $\mod 17$ as well and get $r = 0 \mod 17$. What further details do you need?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Excellent help. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. It was interesting to figured out where the problem was precisely. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Note the question has been *heavily* revised since this answer was written. Originally it asked only how to use Euclid's algorithm to invert $-32\,$ modulo $\,16$]

Mod $\,m,\ $ if $\ 0\,$ has an inverse $\,0^{-1}$ then $\,1 \equiv 00^{-1} \equiv  0\ $ so  $\ m\mid 1\!-\!0 = 1,\ $ therefore $\ m = 1.\,$ This implies that *every* integer $\,n\equiv 0\,$ since  $\, n\equiv n\cdot 1\equiv n\cdot 0 \equiv 0.\,$ Thus $\,0\,$ is invertible only in the degenerate case when the modulus $= 1$, i.e. only in a trivial one element ring $\,\Bbb Z_1 = \{0\}.$

**Note** $\,\  a\,$ is invertible $\iff a\mid 1\,\pmod m\iff ax\equiv 1\pmod m\,$ for some integer $\,x$

Let's consider  more generally *all* multiples $\,x\,$ of $\,a\,$ mod $\,m.\,$ We have

$\begin{align} a\mid x\!\! \pmod m&\iff  x \equiv aj\!\! \pmod m\ \ \ {\rm for\ some\ integer\ } j\\
&\iff x = aj + mk\quad\ \ {\rm for\ some\ integers\ } j,k\end{align}$

By Bezout we know the set $\, a\Bbb Z + m\Bbb Z = d\Bbb Z\ $ for $\, d =\gcd(a,m)$

Therefore $\ a\mid x\pmod m\iff \gcd(a,m)\mid x$

Therefore $\ a\mid 1\pmod m\iff \gcd(a,m)\mid 1\ \iff \gcd(a,m) = 1$

i.e. $\,\ a\,$ is invertible mod $\,m\iff a\,$ is coprime to $\,m.$

Comment: My question has since been updated. I have removed the downvote.

Comment: @unseen_rider It is never a good idea to change your question since it makes (pending) answers look strange (as it did to mine). I did not see the changes you made till after I posted my answer. It is not very polite to downvote an answer because the answerer had not seen the heavy changes you made to your question.

Comment: That was not the reason I down voted it earlier. The reason was at the time I could not see how your answer was relevant, however I took a fresh look and saw how it was relevant.

Comment: @unseen_rider When that occurs it is more constructive to ask for elaboration. Downvoting doesn't communicate to the answerer which point(s) were not clear to you.

Comment: Ok will consider going forward