# Determining lower and upper bound $B$ in Pollard $p-1$

Tags: prime-numbers, cryptography

Two primes were chosen $p = 463258741983258799 $ and $q = 589654173654089659$ to form a product $n = pq$. Some crypto professor wants to demonstrate the Pollard $p - 1 $ algorithm which uses a parameter $B$. What are his choices for $B$ to successfully factor $n$? What is the smallest good $B$ and what is the largest good $B$?

I have read a lot but I have not find an formula for the bound of B. I am not sure if I am suppose to write $p$ and $q$ in terms of exponential. Any hint or help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are defining $B$ in my opinion.

See [Using Pollards rho algorithm for logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898233/using-pollards-rho-algorithm-for-logarithms)

Also please update your question with a link to relevant research you have done for the bound $B$.